# What is the correct test for differences of proportions with this design?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I have a series of questions with binary choices, which are coded as 1 and 0. I created a percentage by adding up the "1" responses and dividing by the total number of questions. For example, for one respondent, if they gave a "1" response for 6 out of 10 questions, their rate would be 60%.

The design of the study is so that there are two different groups of respondents. One group got series A questions, and the other group got series B questions. Then, I calculated the mean percentage for each group. Series A is the control, while series B is the treatment. What is the correct statistical test to see whether there is a significant difference between these mean percentages?

Comment: You could make a contingency table of your data and then use a chisquare test.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with the suggestion on contingency tables and chi-square testing as it won't help you test the difference between means.  You've used your 10 questions to create a *rating scale*, and with that scale, means do apply.

People do differ as to how finely grained a variable must be before one can legitimately test means.  You'll see many disagreements over variables measured on a 1-5 scale.  But with a 0-10 scale, very few would object to the use of a means test.

You used the "proportions" tag.  It's true that proportions are involved to the extent that each person gives a "1" response to some proportion of the 10 questions. But once you go beyond the 0's and 1's and deal with the *scale scores* (what you call "ratings"), you are interested in the comparing the mean for the entire group, A vs. B.  You no longer need think about proportions at that point, just the mean of each set of scores. So a test of the difference between means (z-test or t-test for independent samples) is what you're after.

To illustrate why "proportion" no longer applies, suppose one group's scores are {.6, .3, .6, .6, .4}.  You could transform all such scores to {6, 3, 6, 6, 4} or even {60, 30, 60, 60, 40} without affecting a t-test's results.